# Remove node from a linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm making a dictionary type program with LinkedList, but I cant use the LinkedList utility, I have to create my own, so I can't use any of those methods, I have to remove a node, and I can't for the life of me figure it out. I can do it on paper, but in the code, it either removes everything before it, or just freezes and such. Here's what I have so far on the delete method:

```
void delete(String w)
{ 
        WordMeaningNode temp = list;
        WordMeaningNode current = list;
        WordMeaningNode back = null;
        boolean found = false;
        while(current != null && !found)
        {
            if( current.WordMeaning.getTitle().equals(w))
            {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("found it!");
            }
            else
            {
                back = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
         temp = current.next; //this is where the problem starts
         back.next = temp;
         }
}
```

and here's how I'm calling it:

```
String delWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word to be deleted");
                WordMeaning.delete(delWord);
```

or maybe I'm just not understanding the coding concept, what my teacher wants is not actually "delete" the node, just redirect the node before the current, to the node after the current, can anyone help me please?

Comment: is it doubly linked list / circular linked list / single Linked List ?. In Single linked List you can't traverse back . So you have to loop from start to find the element and delete it

Comment: it is a single Linked List
A-->B-->C-->D--|
like that

Comment: in this case. your list variable always should point to first element in List. And @Wintermute answer is perfect for your question if the list points to first element. Only one thing you should think about is  to set back the current Object points to 1. Else it would fail

Comment: To avoid these kind of traverse issue. try to implement double linked list. Java LinkedList is double headed

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean deleteMiddleNode(Node middleNode)
{
//error check:
if  (middleNode  ==  null  ||  middleNode.next  ==  null)
return false;

/*
middleNode is x in our example data above, but
is now changed to hold the data of node y:
*/
middleNode.data = middleNode.next.data;

/*tempNode now holds node z if following
the example above:  */
Node tempNode = middleNode.next.next;
//delete the old node Y from example above
delete(middleNode.next);
/*reset pointer so that the new "y" points
  to z
*/
middleNode.next = tempNode;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant use this because i can use a delete method :/

Answer (score 0):

The "skipping" of the delete nodes needs to be in the matching if-statment.

Assumption 1: The variable 'list' always points to the first element of the list.

Assumption 2: The list is not circular. Otherwise the algorithm may not terminate.

But you also have to treat border cases (empty list, list with one element, if you delete the first entry) in addition to the implementation below.

```
 void delete(String w) { 
    WordMeaningNode current = list;
    WordMeaningNode back = null;
    boolean found = false;
    while(current != null && !found)
    {
        if( current.WordMeaning.getTitle().equals(w))
        {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("found it!");
            back.next = current.next;
        }
        else
        {
            back = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: what if the word stay beyond the current ? if the Linked list is not circular

Comment: Example: "Node 1" -> "Node 2" -> "Node 3". With the code above, you can delete "Node 2" and "Node 3". "Node 1" will result in a NullPointerException. Can you explain your comment a bit more?

Comment: Assume , you have Node 1 -> Node 2 - > Node 3 - Node 4 . and the current point to Node 3. if user wants to delete Node 1 . The above code would not work unless current is Node 1

Comment: he has not given information about How he implemented the Linked List.

Comment: "Node 1" will result in a NullPointerException . Not true. because the while loop terminate and the Node 1 would not delete and will not throw exception

Comment: Okay. I got your point. My expectation is, that the variable 'list' always points to the first node. And that there is no circular list. Otherwise, the algorithm may never terminate.